# I must solve this by using boolean algebra rules but i dont know how

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've got this problem there which I have no idea how to solve (by using **boolean algebra rules**).
$$
b\bar{c} + ba + \bar{a}\bar{c}
$$

I have to simplify it and I don't know which rule should I use.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Well I'm thinking about this for about an hour but I just cant figure it out. I must must have overlooked something important.

Answer (score 0):

We make use of the the distributive property and the fact that in Bollean Algebra it holds that $x \bar{x}=0$ $\forall x$.

So we have $$b\bar{c} + ba + \bar{a}\bar{c}=\\b\bar{c} + ba + \bar{a}\bar{c}+a\bar{a}=\\b(a+\bar{c})+\bar{a}(a+\bar{c})=\\(a+\bar{c})(b+\bar{a})$$

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't match with my final result which should look like this:
$$ab\ + \bar{a}\bar{c}\\$$

Comment: @Zdenda Perhaps you should have bothered writing the result you wish to reach in the first place. Ok, can you make a table of all possible values of $a,b,c$? That will answer your question. In the meantime I will try to see how we can go there by exploiting basic properties.

Answer (score 0):

The [Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem) says that:

**Consensus**

$$pq + \bar q  r + p  r = p  q + \bar q  r$$

With Consensus, you can simplify your expression in 1 step:

$$
b\bar{c} + ba + \bar{a}\bar{c} = \text{ (Consensus)}
$$

$$
ba + \bar{a}\bar{c}
$$

.. but you probably weren't given Consensus. So, let's prove Consensus:

**Consensus**

$$pq + \bar q  r + p  r = p  q + \bar q  r$$

Proof:

$$p  q + \bar q  r + p  r = \text{ (Adjacency)} $$

$$p  q + \bar q  r + p  q  r + p  \bar q  r = \text{ (Absorption)} $$

$$p  q + \bar q  r$$

And if you don't have Adjacency or Absorption:

**Adjacency**

$$p = p  q + p  \bar q$$

Proof:

$$p = \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$p  1 = \text{ (Complement)}$$

$$p  (q + \bar q) = \text{ (Distribution)}$$

$$p  q + p  \bar q$$

**Absorption**

$$p + p  q = p$$

Proof:

$$p + p  q = \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$p  1 + p  q = \text{ (Distribution)}$$

$$p ( 1 + q )= \text{ (Annihilation)}$$

$$p  1 = \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$p$$